# Syntax error when trying to alias in SAS EG 7.1

Tags: sql, sas

[Can't alias a new column as something with spaces, tried with single quote/double quote still syntax error. Only way i can run the statement is if the birthmonth is written without spaces or separated with underscore birth_month. pls help :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSvNa.png)

[Other premade columns that came with the dataset have Titles with spaces, mine can't be made with spaces and can only be separated using a underscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr9jb.png)

Comment: Tried `"Birth month"`? I'd go with birth_month anyway.

Comment: Yeah tried "Birth month" 'Birth month' . SAS eg doesnt only allows use of underscore without the quotes, but is there a reason why the underscore is mandatory? Because the dataset (that someone made) that i was using has column names like Employee Gender with spaces displayed and no underscore unless it's displayed in the log(then it'll have a underscore). How do i get the new column birth month to be displayed like Employee Gender with a space without the use of a underscore showing?

Comment: SAS variable names are supposed to follow rules where only letters, numbers and underscores can be used. If your program has a variable name with a space, the SAS compiler will see this as 2 separate words, try to use the first as the variable name, and then throw a syntax error because it wasn't expecting the second. Using `"variable name"n` notation tells SAS explicitly that everything inside the quotes (including the sapce) is part of the variable name.

Comment: What type of screen is that photograph that appears to show names with spaces a photograph of? Are you sure those are the NAMES of the variables and not the LABELS?  Please post text as text and not photographs.  Use PROC CONTENTS or other method to actually check the definition of the variables and not just printout or browser screens.

Answer (score 0):

Use the name literal `"birth month"n` to create a variable with spaces in the name.